# rsync brace expansion not working

Tags: rsync

I cant seem to get `rsync` to `include` with brace expansion properly. Say in my current directory I have three file `test.py`, `test.sh` and `test.html`. I want to transfer only files ending in `.py` and `.sh`. I tried:

```
rsync -zrv --include *.{py,sh} --exclude '*' . USER@SERVER:~
```

But this only transfers the python file. If I swap around the order in the braces to say `{sh,py}` then it only transfers the shell script.

Finally, if I do

```
rsync -zrv --include *.sh --include *.py --exclude '*' . USER@SERVER:~
```

it transfers both the files all ok. Seems like it doesn't like brace expansion?

Comment: Have you tried `--include='*.'{py,sh}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the shell isn't quite interpreting it correctly, use the following notation to supply multiple extensions:

```
--include='*.'{py,sh}
```